# How to keep CheckBox persistence in Gridview Android (handling checkbox state)?

Tags: java, android, checkbox, persistence, android-gridview

I am working on an app where i am using custom gridview with images & checkboxes. Displaying of gridview with images & checkboxes is working good. But here my issue is after make one checkbox checked if i scroll the gridview another checkbox is checked & again if i scroll down again it is displaying. Here checkbox checked state was maintaing. My Adapterclass Code is..

MyGrid.java

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public ImageAdapter() {
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.galleryitem, null);
            holder.imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.thumbImage);
            holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.itemCheckBox);
            holder.textview = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.saved_image_name);

            Drawable background = holder.textview.getBackground();
            background.setAlpha(150);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.textview.setId(position);

        holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton arg0, boolean arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) holder.checkbox;

                int id = cb.getId();

                if (thumbnailsselection[id]) {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                    selected_images.remove(String.valueOf(id));
                } else {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                    if (selected_images.contains(String.valueOf(id))) {

                    }else{
                        selected_images.add(String.valueOf(id));
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                int id = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + arrPath[id]),
                "image/*");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        if (arrPath[position] == null || arrPath[position].equals(null)) {

        }else{
        image_name=extractString(arrPath[position]);
        String[] splited_name = image_name.split("\\.");

        for (int i = 0; i < selected_images.size(); i++) {
            if (selected_images.get(i).equals(String.valueOf(position)) || selected_images.get(i) == String.valueOf(position)) {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
            }
        }

        holder.textview.setText(splited_name[0]);
        holder.imageview.setImageBitmap(thumbnails[position]);
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);
        holder.id = position;

        holder.imageview.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}

class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageview;
    CheckBox checkbox,checkbox1;
    TextView textview;
    int id;
}
```

Can anyone help me how to maintain the persistence state of checkbox (selected checkbox).

Comment: you want the check box checked to maintain state when scrolling? suppose  check box of row one( is checked when you scroll up and down only check box of row one is checked. is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes.. exactly i am looking for that solution.

Comment: what part of the code are you getting confused?

Answer (score 1):

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/android-developers/No0LrgJ6q2M

Drawing from romain guy's solution of listview in the above link.

Your Custom Adapter must implement `CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener` and use a `SparseBooleanArray`

Then

```
 cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false)); 
 cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
```

Then

```
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
        return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
    }

    public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
        mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

    }

    public void toggle(int position) {
        setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
    }
@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
        boolean isChecked) {
     mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    

}
```

Example

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    int count;
private CheckBoxAdapter mCheckBoxAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final GridView gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    gridView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    mCheckBoxAdapter = new CheckBoxAdapter(this);
           gridView.setAdapter(mCheckBoxAdapter);

   }

public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int
position, long id) {
    mCheckBoxAdapter.toggle(position);
}

class CheckBoxAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener
{  private SparseBooleanArray mCheckStates;
   LayoutInflater mInflater;
    ImageView imageview1,imageview;
    CheckBox cb;

    CheckBoxAdapter(MainActivity context)
    {
        super(context,0);
        mCheckStates = new SparseBooleanArray(10);
        mInflater = (LayoutInflater)MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 10;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
         vi = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.checkbox, null); 
         imageview= (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

         cb = (CheckBox) vi.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);

         cb.setTag(position);
         cb.setChecked(mCheckStates.get(position, false));
        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
        return vi;
    }
     public boolean isChecked(int position) {
            return mCheckStates.get(position, false);
        }

        public void setChecked(int position, boolean isChecked) {
            mCheckStates.put(position, isChecked);

        }

        public void toggle(int position) {
            setChecked(position, !isChecked(position));
        }
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
            boolean isChecked) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         mCheckStates.put((Integer) buttonView.getTag(), isChecked);    

    }

}

}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent">
     <GridView
     android:id="@+id/lv"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:numColumns="2"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

checkbox.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginRight="22dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Similar to the one answered here. Instead of listview use gridview and instead of textview use imageview.

[How to change the text of a CheckBox in listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168814/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-checkbox-in-listview/17169411#17169411)

Comment: see the code before the edit. You should be able to modify looking at the example. What part are you confused?

Answer (score 0):

The cells are reused. In `getView()` where you are setting the id's, you should also set the state of the checkbox `holder.checkbox..setChecked(thumbnailsselection[position]);`. Also it isn't recommended to change the id's, if you want to save the position use `setTag()` and put the position there, the views already have id's in the layout.