# CustomListView with checkbox issues?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-custom-view, android-checkbox

Hi I've created `CustomListView` with checkbox. When I click first item, it automaically enable third item also. How to solve it?

```
holder.orderCheckBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {                      
   if(((CheckBox)v).isChecked()) {
     checkboxstate[position]=true;  
     if(observationDetailsList.get(position).LaboratoryUid.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(GlobalVariables.UUIDEmpty.toString()))
     {
        displayWarning();
     }       
     patientOrderList.add(orderDetailsList.get(position));
     patientObservationList.add(observationDetailsList.get(position));

  } else {
    checkboxstate[position]=false;
    patientOrderList.remove(orderDetailsList.get(position));
    patientObservationList.remove(observationDetailsList.get(position));
  }
 }
});
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168814/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-checkbox-in-listview/17169411#17169411. check this might help.

Comment: http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/multi-selection-listview-android-with.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is the complete adapter class to handle this

i am using a toogle button for that and the same you can do with check box you have to maintain state of check boxes

```
public class SettingsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements 
{
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private DealsSTRUC[] setings_Adapt_Catagories;
    Context mContext;
    String isNotificationEnnabled;

    public SettingsListAdapter( Context context, DealsSTRUC[] catagories ,String isEnnabled)
        {
            mContext = context;
            setings_Adapt_Catagories = catagories;
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            isNotificationEnnabled=isEnnabled;
        }

    @Override
    public int getCount()
        {
            return setings_Adapt_Catagories.length;
        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0)
        {
            return null;
        }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position)
        {
            return 0;
        }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            SettingsAdptorViewHolder holder;
            if (convertView == null)
                {
                    convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_settingslist, null);
                    holder = new SettingsAdptorViewHolder();
                    holder.settings_catagory = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settings_lable_text);
                    holder.settings_list_checkbox = (ToggleButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.settings_checkbox);
                    holder.settings_list_checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v)
                                {
                                    ToggleButton cb = (ToggleButton) v;
                                    if (cb.isChecked() == true)
                                        {
                                            setings_Adapt_Catagories[position].setStatus("true");
                                        }
                                    else
                                        {
                                            setings_Adapt_Catagories[position].setStatus("false");
                                        }
                                }
                        });
                    convertView.setTag(holder);
                }
            else
                {
                    holder = (SettingsAdptorViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                }
            if(setings_Adapt_Catagories[position].getStatus().equals("true")&&isNotificationEnnabled.equals("on"))
                {
                    holder.settings_list_checkbox.setChecked(true);                     
                }
            else if(setings_Adapt_Catagories[position].getStatus().equals("false"))
                {
                    holder.settings_list_checkbox.setChecked(false);
                }               
            holder.settings_catagory.setText(setings_Adapt_Catagories[position].getDealName());
            return convertView;
        }

    class SettingsAdptorViewHolder
        {
            TextView settings_catagory;
            ToggleButton settings_list_checkbox;
        }
}
```

Comment: No this is not working same problem having.If i have selected First position item means third item also enable farrukh