# Android list view each with a checkbox

Tags: android

I have a list view whose list item include a text view and a checkbox. Textview gets its data from the database. So my listview consists of multiple textviews each with a checkbox. My problem is that i am unable to map each checkbox to the corresponding list item

Comment: make a custom adapter for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17168814/how-to-change-the-text-of-a-checkbox-in-listview/17169411#17169411. you can check this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a layout like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="8dp" >


<TextView

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="18sp"
  />


<CheckBox

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />



  </LinearLayout >
```

use it in custom adapter
Custom Adapter:

```
    public class AttendeeAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater inflator = null;
private ArrayList<String> attendeeList = null;

public AttendeeAdapter(Context context, int resource,
        List<String> objects) {
    super(context, resource, objects);

    attendeeList = (ArrayList<String>) objects;
    inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.client_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
        holder.txtViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtViewClientName);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String attendee = attendeeList.get(position);

    holder.txtViewName.setText("name");
    return  convertView;
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView txtViewName = null;
            public CheckBox check= null;
}

 }
```

R.layout.client_row is custom layout which contains textview and check box

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I have a problem. I tried to set the custom adapter for the list view like so `reminderListAdapter ListAdapter = new reminderListAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_entry, source_cols);
  reminderListView.setAdapter(reminderListAdapter);` Source_cols is actually a `String[]` but the Adapter expects a List, How do i tackle this problem? source_cols is actually an array of column names from my database

Comment: i think u should write code like
reminderListAdapter listAdapter = new reminderListAdapter(this, R.layout.reminder_entry, source_cols); reminderListView.setAdapter(listAdapter );

Answer (score 0):

Use **ViewHolder** class to bind your listview.

following is example of view holder m using to set friends names and checkbox at each row in listview

//Array Adapter to display friend names on Listview

```
                  public class FriendAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BinforFacebook>
                  {
                      ImageLoader loader=new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());
                      Bitmap res;
                      String url;
                      ArrayList<BinforFacebook> namelist = new ArrayList<BinforFacebook>(); 

                      public FriendAdapter(Context context,int textViewResourceId,ArrayList<BinforFacebook> objects)
                        {
                            super(getApplicationContext(), textViewResourceId, objects);
                            this.namelist=objects;
                            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
                        }

                      @Override
                        public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                                ViewGroup parent) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          ContactsViewHolder viewHolder;

                        //  loader.clearCache();

                          Log.v("in get View","ger View of new create miline");

                          if (convertView == null) {

                                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.friendsnameadd, parent, false);
                                viewHolder = new ContactsViewHolder();
                                viewHolder.txtname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_contact);
                                viewHolder.txtmilineuptag = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tagmilineup);
                                viewHolder.chkmiteam = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Checkmilineup);
                                viewHolder.frndimg = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.frndimg);

                              //adding facebook friend id into list to store in database and to post image to their wall  

                                viewHolder.chkmiteam.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                                    @Override
                                    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                          int getPosition = (Integer) buttonView.getTag(); 

                                          namelist.get(getPosition).setFlag((buttonView.isChecked())); // Set the value of checkbox to maintain its state.
                                          if(isChecked)
                                          {
                                              Log.v("namelist id",namelist.get(getPosition).getFbid().toString());
                                                 if(!fbidlist_todb.contains(namelist.get(getPosition).getFbid().toString()))
                                                 {
                                                     fbidlist_todb.add(namelist.get(getPosition).getFbid().toString());
                                                 }
                                                  else
                                                  {
                                                      fbidlist_todb.remove(namelist.get(getPosition).getFbid());
                                                  }
                                          }
                                    }
                                });

                                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
                                convertView.setTag(R.id.name_contact, viewHolder.txtname);
                                convertView.setTag(R.id.tagmilineup, viewHolder.txtmilineuptag);
                                convertView.setTag(R.id.Checkmilineup, viewHolder.chkmiteam);
                                convertView.setTag(R.id.frndimg, viewHolder.frndimg);
                            }
                            else {
                                viewHolder = (ContactsViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                            }

                            viewHolder.chkmiteam.setTag(position); // This line is important.  
                            viewHolder.txtname.setText(namelist.get(position).getFbname());
                            viewHolder.chkmiteam.setChecked(namelist.get(position).flag);

                            url=(namelist.get(position).getUrl());
                            Log.v("url in getview",url);
                      //      viewHolder.frndimg.setImageBitmap(namelist.get(position).getB1());
                            loader.DisplayImage(url,viewHolder.frndimg);

                            /*checking if current position friend is already added in to team or not.
                             * if added then make checkbox checked
                             */

                            if(namelist.get(position).getFbid()!=null)
                            {
                                Log.v("fb name list uid",namelist.get(position).getFbid());
                                 for(int i=0;i<fbidlist_fromdb.size();i++)
                                    {
                                        if(namelist.get(position).getFbid().equals(fbidlist_fromdb.get(i).toString()))
                                        {
                                            viewHolder.chkmiteam.setChecked(true);
                                        }
                                    }
                            }

                          return convertView;
                        }
                  }
```